# Doctrine: Use "WITH PARSER" clause for fulltext index definition

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 3.3.10 and MySQL 5.7.18, and trying to use a fulltext index like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="article", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="body_idx", columns={"body"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
```

With this entity definition, `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` gives

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX body_idx ON article (body);
```

but I want to use [`WITH PARSER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) like

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX body_idx ON article (body) WITH PARSER mecab;
```

Question: *How can I achieve this?* My intuitive is any of the following would be the strategy, but I've not come to the answer: 1) configuring ORM\Index's option to add an extra string to the query or 2) somehow using raw SQL to build the query.